# pdfminer.pdfpage.PDFPage.get_pages() | Error in 'password' attribute

Tags: python, pdfminer

#### Environment

- Python: Python 3.8.5
- pdfminer: 20191125

---

#### Exception

```
{
   "trace":[
      {
         "filename":"/project/test.py",
         "name":"foo",
         "lineno":49
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfpage.py",
         "name":"get_pages",
         "lineno":122
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py",
         "name":"__init__",
         "lineno":575
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py",
         "name":"_initialize_password",
         "lineno":599
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py",
         "name":"__init__",
         "lineno":300
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py",
         "name":"init",
         "lineno":307
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py",
         "name":"init_key",
         "lineno":320
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py",
         "name":"authenticate",
         "lineno":368
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py",
         "name":"authenticate_user_password",
         "lineno":374
      },
      {
         "filename":"/project/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pdfminer/pdfdocument.py",
         "name":"compute_encryption_key",
         "lineno":351
      }
   ]
}
```

---

#### Problem Statement

I'm using pdfminer which is a tool, that can be used with Python3 for extracting information from PDF documents. The problem is there is no good documentation at all and no source code example on how to use the tool.

I have already tried some code from StackOverflow but it didn't work. Below is my code.

---

#### Code Snippet

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter

def foo(path, password, bankname):
    rsrcmgr = PDFResourceManager()
    retstr = io.StringIO()
    codec = 'utf-8'
    laparams = LAParams()
    device = TextConverter(rsrcmgr, retstr, laparams=laparams)
    fp = open(path, 'rb')
    interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(rsrcmgr, device)
    maxpages = 2
    caching = True
    pagenos = set()
    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fp, pagenos, maxpages=maxpages, password=password, caching=caching,
                                  check_extractable=False):  # This is Line 49
        interpreter.process_page(page)
    text = retstr.getvalue()
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: you didn't ask question in question's body.

Comment: you can try `help( PDFPage.get_pages )` to display docstrings from source code (if it has it) and maybe there will be something useful. You can also `print( pdfminer.pdfpage.__file__ )` to get path to source code and check what this function may expect.

Answer (score 0):

try to insert password = "" before for instructions.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).